# Initialize and use 2d vector of structs

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I am trying to initialize a 2d vector of structs having

```
vector <vector <cellValue>> table;

mStringX = X;
mStringY = Y;

mLengthX = X.length();
mLengthY = Y.length();

vector<cellValue> myRow (0, mLengthY);

table.push_back(myRow);
```

Of my struct `cellValue`

```
struct cellValue
{
    int stringLength;
    arrow direction;
};
```

And using a couple places in my code with

```
table[i, j]->stringLength = table[i - 1, j - 1]->stringLength + 1;
```

However I have a feeling I am using vectors completely wrong. I am new to vectors and I have been told they are similar to arrays.

Comment: Don't do `table[i, j]` this effectively means that you are doing `table[j]`. Do `table[i][j]` instead.

Comment: Ah yes, the infamous [comma operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out what I was doing wrong. When I was initializing my vector, I needed to declare is `table = vector<vector<cellValue>> (mLengthX, vector<cellValue>(mLengthY));` and whenever I was accessing the values of `table` I needed to do `table[i][j].stringLength` instead of `table[i, j]->stringLength`